# Multiple ListViews in RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I want to have multiple `listViews` underneath each one of my `RecyclerView` items. Initially, each one will be hidden, but when the user taps on a call log item, the item will expand, revealing the details underneath, as seen below. I have a `List` variable, which holds all available log details, and which I pass into my ListView:

```
mLogsList.setAdapter(new HistoryLogAdapter(
     view.getContext(), R.layout.history_detail_cell, mLogs));
```

When I print mLogs out, it shows all available log details, but when I pass it onto the `RecyclerView` item, it always just displays the first log, for all entries.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Further context:

```
List<CallLog> mLogs = Arrays.asList(LinphoneManager.getCore().getCallLogs());

            CallLog log = mLogs.get(getAdapterPosition());
            Address address = log.getFromAddress();

            String mSipUri = (address != null) ? address.asString() : "";

            if (mSipUri != null) {
                address = Factory.instance().createAddress(mSipUri);

                Core core = LinphoneManager.getCore();
                if (address != null && core != null) {
                    address.clean();
                    ProxyConfig proxyConfig = core.getDefaultProxyConfig();
                    CallLog[] logs;
                    if (proxyConfig != null) {
                        logs = core.getCallHistory(address, proxyConfig.getIdentityAddress());
                    } else {
                        logs = core.getCallHistoryForAddress(address);
                    }

                    mLogsList.setAdapter(
                            new HistoryLogAdapter(
                                    view.getContext(), R.layout.history_detail_cell, mLogs));
                    mLogsList.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                    mLogsList.setEnabled(false);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate your effort but in my opinion, you can treat your listItem as a section. 
There is a very good and handy library for expandable RecyclerView. Your case is very popular and personally I faced this before.
So I recommend using [this library](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) It would provide you with a solution for sectioned RecyclerView. and to be me more specific you can see [this example](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/tree/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/demo/example4) for expandable sectioned RecyclerView.

I hope this would help.

Comment: Thank you Mustafa, I will have a look into it!